# Convertir consulta select CROSS APPLY a LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo una consulta de selección `SELECT` que implementa `CROSS APPLY` y tengo la necesidad de pasarlo a LINQ

Transact SQL Server

```
SELECT distinct(PC.ProductoCatalogoId),
P.Nombre + ' ' + PL.Product + ' ' + E.Nombre + ' ' + O.NombreOpcion AS   Descripcion,
    PC.PrecioVenta
FROM ProductoCatalogos AS PC
INNER JOIN Productos AS P ON PC.ProductoId = P.ProductoId
INNER JOIN EspecificacionCatalogos AS EC ON PC.ProductoCatalogoId = EC.ProductoCatalogoId 
INNER JOIN EspecificacionProductos AS EP ON EC.EspecificacionProductoId = EP.EspecificacionProductoId
INNER JOIN Especificaciones AS E ON EP.EspecificacionId = E.EspecificacionId
AND E.EspecificacionId = 2
INNER JOIN Opciones AS O ON EC.OpcionId = O.OpcionId
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT E.Nombre + ' ' + O.NombreOpcion AS 'Product'
    FROM ProductoCatalogos AS PC
    INNER JOIN Productos AS P ON PC.ProductoId = P.ProductoId
    INNER JOIN EspecificacionCatalogos AS EC ON PC.ProductoCatalogoId = EC.ProductoCatalogoId
    INNER JOIN EspecificacionProductos AS EP ON EC.EspecificacionProductoId = EP.EspecificacionProductoId
    INNER JOIN Especificaciones AS E ON EP.EspecificacionId = E.EspecificacionId
        AND E.EspecificacionId = 5
    INNER JOIN Opciones AS O ON EC.OpcionId = O.OpcionId

    ) PL
    WHERE P.Nombre LIKE '%ferr%'
```

LINQ, tengo el siguiente consulta no he podido avanzar mas porque no se como implementar `CROSS APPLY` en LINQ

```
public IEnumerable<ProductoCatalogo> SearchProduct(int colorId, int tallaId)
    {
        using (var context = new BusinessContext())
        {
            var result = from pc in context.ProductoCatalogos
                join p in context.Productos on pc.ProductoId equals p.ProductoId
                join ec in context.EspecificacionCatalogos on pc.ProductoCatalogoId equals ec.ProductoCatalogoId
                join ep in context.EspecificacionProductos on ec.EspecificacionProductoId equals ep.EspecificacionProductoId
                join e in context.Especificaciones on ep.EspecificacionId equals e.EspecificacionId
                join o in context.Opciones on ec.OpcionId equals o.OpcionId
        }
    }
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Saludos!